# Cell Animation Stops when swipe left/right or pull table view out of screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

I can't figure out why animation of tableViewcell frizzes when tableView is pulled out out of screen or stoppes when you start to close menu.

To let you better understand the problem, here is a gif

[image]

I implement Tap Gesture Recognizer at custom UITableViewCell Class

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapAction")
         self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

func tapAction() {  
        let animationWidth = leftMenuWidth * 0.27
               UIView.animateWithDuration(0.75, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .AllowUserInteraction, animations: {
            self.colorIndicator.frame.size.width += animationWidth
            }) { (true) in
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.75, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .AllowUserInteraction, animations: { 
                    self.colorIndicator.frame.size.width -= animationWidth
                    }, completion: { (true) in
                        print("Animation Complete")
                })
        }
```

Also i implement sliding menu by using this cocoaPods - https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu

Thanks.

Comment: I would say that the animation gets interrupted and doesn't get to finished when a cell goes invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cells are likely being reloaded which is causing the animations to reset.

Try tracking the state of whether or not a cell has been tapped so that when it's reloaded you can show the animation as already complete. You can do this by with a simple dictionary.

At the top of your view controller, define:

```
private var tapped = [Int : Bool]()
```

Next, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` for your tableView check:

```
if let isSet = tapped[view.hashValue] where isSet == true {
    // display animation complete. You probably don't want to re-animate
    // it if it's scrolled back into view, so just get it to the completed state.
}
```

Finally, switch your tap action from using a gesture in the cell itself to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` inside your tableView:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // remember the cell has been tapped
    tapped[view.hashValue] = true

    // call your method to display the animation on the cell,
    // something like cell.showAnimation(). It shouldn't animate if
    // already displaying the completed animation state.
}
```

Also, I wouldn't recommend using `+=` or `-=` operators when calculating the frame since calling it multiple times will keep growing or shrinking it. Use explicit values instead, like `= animationWidth` or `= 0`.